# Detecting support for HTML5 Semantic Elements (NOT adding support)

Tags: javascript, html

I know that you can add support for HTML5 tags in older browsers using this technique:

```
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
```

But how do I **test** support for these elements?

Comment: By "support", do you mean being able to style them, or rather for testing if some functionality is possible (for, say, the range input)?

Comment: Testing whether you need to do the script I posted before doing it.

Comment: It seems (generally speaking) that the only reliable way to test if you need a shim is to try creating the element - have you looked at what the html5shiv does? https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js - the real question is (still) what do you mean by "support"? The shiv just makes it possible to affect those elements with whatever level of CSS the browser supports. Do you need to know more than that (say, if the browser supports `<canvas>`)?